# Correctly bind boolean values in radiogroup

Tags: angular, angular9

I've been battling with these radio buttons for a while but can't seem to have an headway.

I have a list of dynamic answers from the database like so:

```js
answers = [
  { answer: "an answer", valid: false },
  { answer: "second answer", valid: true },
  { answer: "another answer", valid: false },
];
```

I need to be able to bind then to radio buttons like so

```html
<div *ngFor="let ans of answers; let i = index">
  <input
    type="radio"
    id="customRadio{{i}}"
    [(ngModel)]="ans.valid"
    name="exm_qst_vld"
    [checked]="ans.valid==true"
    [value]="ans.valid"
  />
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [(ngModel)]="ans.answer" name="answer{{i}}"></ckeditor>
</div>
```

It does not work. All the radio buttons appear as unchecked. Also clicking them doesn't have any effect.

Does anyone have any ideas

Comment: Is the state of the radiobutton not displaye correctly or is the binding to the specific property not working if changed afterwards?

Comment: The problem is that the second radio button is supposed to appear checked, but it isn't. Basically, all the radio buttons appear unchecked

Comment: remove this part:  `[checked]="ans.valid==true"` and try again

Comment: Thanks @xDrago: 
However, each time I tried that approach, the last radio is checked instead of the 2nd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behavior since no part of your code is ever changing a deselected option's `valid` property to `false`.

Using `ngModel` there should be only a single model representing the currently selected item as demonstrated below:

```js
public answers = [
  { answer: "an answer" },
  { answer: "second answer" },
  { answer: "another answer" },
]

public selected = this.answers[0]
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of answers; let i = index">
  <label [for]="i">{{x.answer}}</label>
  <input type="radio"
    [id]="i"
    [value]="x"
    [(ngModel)]="selected" />
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rafi Henig; the challenge I have is that answers.answer is already bound to a ckeditor ngModel  like so
`
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [(ngModel)]="ans.answer" name="answer{{i}}"></ckeditor>
`.
This means only the ckeditor should manipulate the answer and that is why the boolean values are used to manage the checked state

Comment: `@Abimbola` since there are multiple models how do you expect a `ngModel` to detect a deselection?

Comment: Well @Rafi Henig, I actually don't know.
I felt since I was able to do it in angularjs like so:
`<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="ans in answers">
<label class="switch switch-sm">
                    <input type="radio" name="exm_qst_vld" ng-model="ans.answer" ng-checked="answer.valid" ng-change="qdCtrl.changeAnswer(ans)" ng-value="true" />
                    <span><i class="handle"></i></span>
                </label></div>`
I believed there would be a way also in angular2+

Comment: Meanwhile, the controller of my angularjs app looked like so:
`vm.changeAnswer = function(selectedAnswer){
      angular.forEach(vm.question.answers,function(answer){
             answer.valid= selectedAnswer === answer;
     })
};`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-kilby-j8whm?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks @Ravi Henig. It works!
However, the challenge I am having is that the x.answer is supposed to be for the ckeditor (or textarea) ngModel like so:
`<textarea name="message{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="x.answer"></textarea>` while the boolean is supposed to be for the radio buttons. Is there a way I can identify the selected answer while still managing state of the textarea?

Comment: Please take a look https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-kilby-j8whm?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe the problem is, that 2 of 3 radio-buttons have the same value:

```
<div *ngFor="let ans of answers; let i = index">
     <input type="radio" id="customRadio{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="ans.valid"
         name="exm_qst_vld" [value]="{{i}}" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution would set a selected option's valid property to its index value instead of Boolean value

Comment: Thanks @meDom. However, I had tried this previously. Rafi Henig is right. This sets a selected option's valid property to its index value instead of Boolean value.
Also, the "second answer" does not appear as initially selected even when though it is initially true

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Rafi Henig.
Your solution works, and I am therefore marking it as the correct answer. However, it was not exactly what I was looking for. I dont really like the separation of the answers from the selection radios.

I have decided to go with checkboxes since they seem to work without the hassles.

```
<div *ngFor="let ans of answers; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-state" (click)="ans.valid? false : mcsaClicked(ans)" [(ngModel)]="ans.valid" name="valid{{i}}"/>
  <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [(ngModel)]="ans.answer" name="answer{{i}}"></ckeditor>
<div>
```

Then in the component, I did...

```
mcsaClicked(answer: IAnswer): void {
  this.answers.forEach((ans) => {
      ans.valid= false;
  });
  answer.valid= true;
}
```